# UPDATE with HAVING in duplicate values in Excel

Tags: sql, vba, duplicates

Need help with this issue. I have a Develop, i need find the duplicate values in SQL, after need Sum the INVOICE_AMOUNT and Divide for individualy amount Example.

```
FA-0001 $25.00   BILL-0001
FA-0001 $75.00   BILL-0002.
```

I need SUM TOTAL of this invoice. SUM(AMOUNT_INVOICE)= $100.00, after divide this result with the individual amount. Example 100.00/25=0.25 , etc etc. and this percentage multiply for DET_SOL_AMOUNT.

I need apply this query in duplicate values.

I try with this query.

```
UPDATE [T4DET] SET [DET_SOL]=(([LOC_AMOUNT]/SUM([LOC_AMOUNT]))*[DET_SOL_CALC]) FROM [1WEB] WHERE [1WEB].[INVOICE] IN (SELECT [T4DET].[ASSIGNMENT] FROM [T4DET] GROUP BY [T4DET].[ASSIGNMENT] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to do correctly, it is easy with Excel. You need to write formulas in 2 columns only, for example:

```
Group   Amount  Bill No DET_SOL_CALC    Sum of Group    Result
FA-0001 $25.00  BILL-0001   2   100 0.5
FA-0001 $75.00  BILL-0002   2   100 1.5
FA-0002 $200.00     BILL-0001   5   600 1.666666667
FA-0002 $100.00     BILL-0002   5   600 0.833333333
FA-0002 $300.00     BILL-0003   5   600 2.5
```

Put your data in columns A, B and C
ColumnD: DET_SOL_CALC
Column E formula should be: =SUMIF($A$2:$C$6,A2,$B$2:$B$6)
Column F formula should be: =B2/E2*D2

Row 1 is headers of your data
put these formulas in row to and drag them down to the last row of your data, your numbers should be calculated correctly.

Please hit the check mark if this is your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The alter Solution is, Create a Temporal Table with SUM and GROUP BY and agregate three columns for calculations

Example

DET4TEMP
ASSINGMENT NVARCHAR
DOC_AMOUNT MONEY

```
INSERT INTO 4DETTEMP (ASSINGNMENT,[TOTAL]) ASSIGNMENT, SUM(DOC_AMOUNT) FROM FBL5N GROUP BY ASSIGNMENT
```

and after query is+

Obtain DET SOL Amount in the other table.

```
UPDATE 4BET SET DET_SOL_CAL=T2.INCOMING_AMOUNT FROM FBL5N T2 WHERE ASSIGNMENT=T2.INV_CON
```

Obtain DOC AMOUNT TOTAL of the temporal table.

```
UPDATE 4BET SET DOC_AMNT_TOTAL=T2.[TOTAL] FROM 4DETTEMP T2 WHERE ASSIGNMENT=T2.ASSIGNMENT
```

Obtain the Calculation Percentage.

```
UPDATE 4BET PERC_CAL_AMNT=(DOC_AMNT_TOTAL/DOC_AMNT), DET_SOL=(PERC_CAL_AMNT*DET_SOL_CALC)
```

after delete temp tables and finish.

This is my solution. The question is Viable?